# Cannot use dimen.xml in java android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have these dimensions in my dimens.xml file :

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="test">48dp</dimen>
```

In my java file I have :
float valueInPixels = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.test);

My issue is that "test" is written in red, it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'test'.
It doesn't work in any class of my project but it works when I make it in a new project. I also tried with getDimensionPixelSize() but I still have the issue.

Do you see what's wrong ?

Comment: are you sure that you imported correct `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalidate cache and restart, then perform a clean. The first option can be found in the file menu. The second in the build menu.

Answer (score -1):

Try to rebuild your project/sync it

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing getResources() with current context(getContext() if fragment or getApplicationContext() if Activity)

If it still shows "cannot resolve", hover over red text and hit **ALT+ENTER** from the pop up options choose option for creating dimension value.